# assert_select XML with namespace and prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

Having a XML like the following, how could I `assert_select` the tag `atom:link`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>http://example.com</link>
    <description>Description</description>
    <atom:link href="http://example.com/feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

`assert_select 'title'` works fine.
`assert_select 'atom:link'` outputs `Expected at least 1 element matching "atom:link", found 0..`.

I am using Rails `4.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, according to the [Nokogiri CSS selector](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html), to replace `:` by `|`.

I did not test but it would be `assert_select 'atom|link'`.